# When is $\left\|\hat S\left(\hat S+T\right)^{-1}\right\|_2\le 1$ for p.d. $S$ and $T$?

Tags: random-matrices, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be i.i.d. $N(0,I_{p\times p})$. Let $S$ be the covariance of the $x_i$, $\hat S=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T$.

**What is the set of *positive-definite* $p\times p$ matrices $T$ such that**

$$\left\|\hat S\left(\hat S+T\right)^{-1}\right\|_2\le 1.$$

I had naively assumed that this would always be true, but as [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849131/proving-that-for-p-d-matrices-a-and-b-that-aab-1-21) shows this holds iff

$$T^2+\hat S T+T\hat S\succ 0,$$

which is certainly not guaranteed. Has there been any work on this kind of question? The setting I care about is where $n,p\to\infty$ and $\frac pn\to const$ (and I only require that this hold with high probability). However, in general for positive definite $A$ one could ask for what set of positive definite $B$ does

$$A^2+AB+BA\succ 0.$$

I understand that this may relate to certain results about the Lyapunov equation, but this connection appears tenuous to me.